# Combine 4 different plots together in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have 4 different functions to plot different type of plots. Now each function return a graph of size 20x10.

```
def plot_func1(X,y):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
    ax = sns.hist(X,y)
    plt.show()

def plot_func2(U,v):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
    ax = plt.bar(U,v)
    plt.show()
def plot_func3():
def plot_func4():
```

How can I graph these 4 graph as subgraph ?
The idea is kinda like this

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)
axs[0, 0].plot_func1(x, y)

axs[0, 1].plot_func2(u, v)

axs[1, 0].plot_func3()

axs[1, 1].plot_func4()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a function that takes an axis in parameter and plots onto it:

```
def plot_func1(X, y, ax):
    ax.plot(X, y)

def plot_func2(U, v, ax):
    ax.bar(U, v)
```

Then in the main part, you define the figure and call the plotting functions:

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(20, 10))
plot_func1(X, y, ax[0])
plot_func2(U, v, ax[1])
```

Additionally, you can define this kind of function with a 'creating a new figure' as a default behavior. You can also pass additional arguments to the plot, i.e. to pass a color, a line width, or other `matplotlib` settings accepted by the plotting function used.

```
def plot(x, y, ax=None, *args, **kwargs):
    if ax is None:
        f, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figisze=(10, 10))
    ax.plot(x, y, *args, **kwargs)
```

Personally, I would just include the `**kwargs` to avoid passing unwanted arguments to the plotting function. I prefer an error to be raised in case a non-valid argument is passed.

EDIT: Full code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def plot_func1(X, y, ax, *args, **kwargs):
    ax.plot(X, y, *args, **kwargs)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    f, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True, figsize=(3, 4))
    
    x1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    x2 = [1, 3, 7, 9]
    y = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    
    plot_func1(x1, y, ax[0])
    plot_func1(x2, y, ax[1], color='crimson')
```

Output:

[image: Example plot]

Comment: This does not work, I got 2 empty graphs.

Comment: @seeking_knowledge This does work. Your implementation of my answer must be wrong. I added a full code version.